# Force hide custom field metaboxes

Tags: custom-field, metabox, filters

How can I completely remove the custom fields and the collapse button in the Edit Post/Edit Page custom screen, but without removing the capability to add custom fields with a PHP function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_meta_box

```
function remove_custom_meta_form() {
    remove_meta_box( 'postcustom', 'post', 'normal' );
    remove_meta_box( 'postcustom', 'page', 'normal' );
}
add_action( 'admin_menu' , 'remove_custom_meta_form' );
```

HTH

Comment: glad I could help

Answer (score 2):

This is how to do it for all post types:

```
add_action( 'do_meta_boxes', 'remove_default_custom_fields_meta_box', 1, 3 );
function remove_default_custom_fields_meta_box( $post_type, $context, $post ) {
    remove_meta_box( 'postcustom', $post_type, $context );
}
```

Comment: Thankfully, this works for the block editor, too!